# How to deploy my conda env to a VPS using fabric or othervise?

Tags: django, conda, vps, fabric, deploying

I made a website using mezzanine-Django , and used conda env to contain it (I should have used virtual env).
but the fabric file is tuned to only deploy virtual envs. What should I do to get my conda env up in the VPS , is there an easy way or should I be installing every packages inside manually?

Answer (score -1):

I would assume you have already created the virtual environment, then what you have to do is:

Put all python packages you want to install for your project inside `requirements.txt`

```
from fabric import task

    @task(hosts=["servername"])
    def do_things(c):
        with c.cd('your_dir'):
            # assuming you already added myenv to your path 
            with c.prefix('source activate myenv'): 
                c.run('pip3.6 install -r requirements.txt') #for example if you have pip3.6
```

You have to use `with c.prefix()` to enable using that environment! And remember you have to run everything within the scope of `with c.prefix('source activate myenv'):` if you want to use the virtual environment.